# how to create multiple rows and columns from a dictionary value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like following

```
id,  values
1, {'foo':2 , 'bar':2}
2, {'baz':20}
and so on
```

I want to transform this dataframe into

```
id val1 val2
1  foo    2
1 bar     2
2 baz     20
```

and so on.. 
I dont want to like iterate each row in dataframe.. as I am pretty sure there is a way in pandas to do the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC PS: you can add `rename` at the end

```
df.set_index('id')['values'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
Out[920]: 
   id level_1     0
0   1     bar   2.0
1   1     foo   2.0
2   2     baz  20.0
```